# Solving a PDE with NDSolveValue with two conditions involving Min function

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to solve a PDE and plot the solution.

```
eqn = D[u[x, t], t] + u[x, t]*D[u[x, t], x] == 0;
cond1 = u[0, t] == 0;
cond2 = u[x, 0] == Min[x, 1];
sol = NDSolveValue[{eqn, cond1, cond2}, u[x, t], {x, 0, 3}, {t, 0, 3}];
Plot3D[sol, {x, 0, 3}, {t, 0, 3}]
```

However, the plot is empty and it shows the following errors:

> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered.
>
> Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0. ComplexInfinity encountered.
>
> NDSolveValue::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at x == 0.
>
> NDSolveValue::dsvar: 0.00021449999999999998` cannot be used as a variable.

Is there a way to fix this. I'm trying to tackle the following problem:

[image: Mathematica solving pde with NDSolveValue having two conditions and min function]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NDSolve` may be dividing by `u[x,t]` before working on the equation and `u` is `0` at `x = 0`.  Moving to `DSolve` instead.

```
eqn = D[u[x, t], t] + u[x, t]*D[u[x, t], x] == 0;

cond1 = u[0, t] == 0
cond2 = u[x, 0] == Min[x, 1]
```

First use `DSolve` without conditions.

```
DSolve[eqn, u[x, t], {x, t}]
(* Solve[u[x, t] == C[1][x - t*u[x, t]], u[x, t]] *)
```

In the result `C[1]` is an arbitrary function rather than a constant.
Look at the equation inside the solve expression. and change `C[1]` to `F` for clarity.

```
eq = u[x, t] == F[x - t*u[x, t]]

eq /. t -> 0
(* u[x, 0] == F[x] *)
```

which from cond2 gives us

```
F[x_] = Min[x, 1]

eq /. x -> 0
(* u[0, t] == Min[1, (-t)*u[0, t]] *)
```

From cond1, this equation is automatically satisfied.

```
eq
(* u[x, t] == Min[1, x - t*u[x, t]] *)

$Assumptions = x > 0 && t > 0

Solve[eq, u[x, t]] // Simplify

{{u[x, t] -> ConditionalExpression[1, t + 1 < x]}, 
  {u[x, t] -> ConditionalExpression[x/(t + 1), t + 1 > x]}}
```

Convert the above to piecewise for evaluation and using both conditions.

```
u[x_, t_] = Piecewise[{{1, t + 1 < x}, {x/(t + 1), t + 1 > x}}]
```

To show it solves original pde

```
eqn // Simplify
(* True *)
```

And Animate a plot.

```
gifs = Table[
   Plot[Evaluate[u[x, t]], {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
    PlotLabel -> t "t"], {t, 0, 10, .05}];
ListAnimate[gifs]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[u[x, t]], {x, 0, 5}, {t, 0, 5}]
```

works too.

**Update**

I got your code to work with one small change in cond1

```
cond1 = u[0, t] == 1/10000000;
```

or it could be any small non-zero value.  It looks like `NDSolve` is dividing the pde by `u` to get `du/dx` at `x = 0` with the predictable failure.  The flat part of the plot is a little wavy, probably due to the abrupt change in slope causing some instability in the numerical solution.